# Storage Access Framework Showing Only Local Storage

Tags: android, kotlin, google-drive-api, storage-access-framework

My app uses Android's Storage Access Framework for storing and retrieving files locally on the device and in the cloud. It has been doing this for a while and worked perfectly.

Now I'm experiencing problems with this functionality on a Samsung Galaxy S20+ running Android 11: only local storage is offered and all cloud location defined e.g. as Google accounts with corresponding Google Drive storage are not available. I suspected changes in Android 11 but could not find any documentation on this. So I tried it in an emulator with Android 11, added my Google account, ran my app - and the Google Drive account showed in the list. Worried something might be wrong in my code, I took some SAF demo app (e.g. from this book I had lying around: https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Accessing_Cloud_Storage_using_the_Android_Storage_Access_Framework) with the same result: works on every other phone and the Android 11 emulator device but not on the S20.

So I suspect I'm dealing with something that is specific to the S20 or my settings on it, but what could it be? Knowing that this might be an exception or misconfiguration on my end is comforting but understanding it would be very useful in case a user contacts me about the same problem.

**Update 2**
In a desperate move, with my everyday use S20+ being the only device showing this behavior, I did a factory reset, reinstalled both apps, and now it's working as expected. That is great but it might not be the last time anyone has seen it. I cannot seriously suggest a factory reset to my users, so I'd really like to understand: what setting or configuration could cause this, or what other installation is mighty enough to make cloud drives disappear from other apps using SAF? Normally, it is enough to add a Google account to the device for Google Drive to appear. I understand there is little hope for an answer but I will leave this question up nevertheless.

**Update**
Upon request, I'm posting the lines for e.g. creating a file:

```
fun createFile(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "file.txt")
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_REQUEST_CODE)
}

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int,
                                     resultData: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CREATE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultData != null) {
                // e.g. add some content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not post minimal code that did not work on that phone.

Comment: Well, actually I did by reference to the example. Based on the observations I doubt the issue is in the code.

Comment: We wait till you post minimal post here.

Comment: @blackapps I added the code from my test app. This is pretty straightforward, and, as I mentioned, it works on every other device and emulator at my disposal. So, unless there are compelling reasons for posting additional code, I won't go further down this path as I fear it distracts from the actual question and problem.

Comment: Which effect has adding category openable?

Comment: @blackapps It has no effect in this basic example other than the type of content shown in the picker. It also does not have any effect on the problem observed. You can ignore it here.

Comment: It is rather mysterious. I appreciate your effort but I seriously think we can ditch the idea of anything being wrong in those few lines of code. I have now done a factory reset with this phone, and, voilà, everything is OK and the Google Drive accounts are visible. As a user, I would be happy now. As a developer, I remain worried that if it happened to me it will happen to others. And since this concerns a backup feature, a factory reset, besides being pretty radical, is the one fix that is not an option here.

Comment: Interesting story. If it happens to you again then first make your device Google account free. Reboot and add your account again. Worth a try i think...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried the reboot, but I will also play next time with removing accounts and adding them again. If that works it definitely is a more "gentle" solution than the reset. Now I just wish I could re-create the issue. :)